# How can I display local HTML in the windows phone web browser?

Tags: html, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I want to use a web browser to present some multimedia information with locally stored HTML files. The problem is that it just presents the static content without any HTML elements, and also doesn't show the images. The sample code is:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(TitleContainer.OpenStream("pathString"));
webBrowser.NavigateToString(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Not sure why some people would downvote a valid question. Even if it is not grammatically correct - you can always fix it...

Comment: What is in reader.ReadToEnd()?

Comment: thanks, just some string look likes "Thank you"in reader.ReadToEnd(),but the html code is"<html><body><h1>Thank you</h1></body></html>",and the font style in webbrowser is not bold

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to copy your html file and images to the same directory in Isolated Storage (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431811(v=vs.92).aspx). Then, you call

`webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("<Location_of_html_file_in_isolatedStorage>", UriKind.Relative))`.

If the images and the html file are in the same directory in isolatedStorage, relative links to your images in this format:

`<img src="../YourImage.jpg"/>`

Will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose the WebBrowser control could get access to any images that might be stored in isolated storage, so all the content you want displayed - you would probably need to somehow embed it in a single html, which would probably require some js code (I am not a js/html expert), which needs to be enabled in the control (IsScriptEnabled if I remember correctly). Otherwise - it might be better to convert your HTML to XAML or just otherwise parse it and display it by code.

Comment: That means I need to write a html a parser for silverlight, that is not a cozy work for me, but thanks all the same